# Next 6 months Data In OBIEE

Tags: obiee

I want to display Next 6 months Data from Current Month in OBIEE 11g.I tried with addmonths() but it shows all years in data,and if i filter on current year it will not shows months in next year.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends - and that why someone voted down your question; it's just not very precise.

What do you want to compare it with? A month number? A month name?

Do you have what's needed? Do you have a properly formed time dimension?

The unclean approach is to use TIMESTAMPADD butwith that you're just curing the symptom, not the root cause.

TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, 6, NOW())

Comment: I want to Show sale booking from current month to next 6 months without any year filter this is 'TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, 6, NOW()) ' fine but what will happen when data lies in 2 years.I have fiscal year Date dimension and i want to filter data on the basis of transaction date or Month

Comment: Have you tried it at all? TIMESTAMPDIFF is a date function so it is aware of years.

Comment: I am using this to filter the data                                                  month("Transaction Date"."DATE")  between MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) and  MONTH(TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, +5,CURRENT_DATE))

Comment: That that will give you exactly what you want. You don't need the "+" sign. As you can see 13 months from now is April.

https://imgur.com/GVk7wqS

Comment: It will shows month for all years available in data not for current year

Comment: Well you DO have to put the notion of year somewhere. If you'd use a properly formed time dimension and the timeseries functions then you wouldn't have the issue.